# How to get the matrix coefficient from a QuadraticForm expression in a very fast way?

Tags: expression-manipulation

As we know, `QuadraticFormDistribution` is the distribution of `z.a.z + b.z + c` for a real-valued p x p symmetric positive definite matrix a, a length-p vector b, a scalar c, and a p-dimensional multivariate normal vector z

I have a `QuadraticFormDistribution` expression `fexp`, which has a very complex form, and it can be simplified to the form `z.a.z + b.z + c`. Now, I want to get the matrix a, the vector b, and the scalar c from `fexp`. I think there are many methods for this simple problem. I always `ExpandAll` the expression `fexp` and use the `Coefficient` to get the matrix a, the vector b and the scalar c.

The problem is: I will deal with very large numbers of these kinds of quadratic expressions, so I want to find a faster method to deal with this problem.

Take an example,

```
fexp=12 - 9 z[3] - 16 z[4] - 25 z[5] - 36 z[6] - 49 z[7] - 64 z[8] - 
81 z[9] - 100 z[10] - 121 z[11] - 144 z[12] + 
k^2 (-1 + 2 z[1] + 2 z[2] + 2 z[3] + 2 z[4] + 2 z[5] + 2 z[6] + 
2 z[7] + 2 z[8] + 2 z[9] + 2 z[10] + 2 z[11] + 2 z[12]) + 
z[1] (-1 + 54 a[1, 2] z[2] + 96 Sqrt[2] a[1, 3] z[3] + 
150 Sqrt[3] a[1, 4] z[4] + 432 a[1, 5] z[5] + 
294 Sqrt[5] a[1, 6] z[6] + 384 Sqrt[6] a[1, 7] z[7] + 
486 Sqrt[7] a[1, 8] z[8] + 1200 Sqrt[2] a[1, 9] z[9] + 
2178 a[1, 10] z[10] + 864 Sqrt[10] a[1, 11] z[11] + 
1014 Sqrt[11] a[1, 12] z[12]) + 
k (1 + 4 a[1, 1] z[1]^2 + 3 z[3] + 4 z[4] + 5 z[5] + 6 z[6] + 
7 z[7] + 8 z[8] + 9 z[9] + 10 z[10] + 11 z[11] + 12 z[12] + 
z[1] (1 + 18 a[1, 2] z[2] + 32 a[1, 3] z[3] + 50 a[1, 4] z[4] + 
   72 a[1, 5] z[5] + 98 a[1, 6] z[6] + 128 a[1, 7] z[7] + 
   162 a[1, 8] z[8] + 200 a[1, 9] z[9] + 242 a[1, 10] z[10] + 
   288 a[1, 11] z[11] + 338 a[1, 12] z[12]) + 
  2 (8 a[2, 2] z[2]^2 + 18 a[3, 3] z[3]^2 + 49 a[3, 4] z[3] z[4] + 
   32 a[4, 4] z[4]^2 + 64 a[3, 5] z[3] z[5] + 
   81 a[4, 5] z[4] z[5] + 50 a[5, 5] z[5]^2 + 
   81 a[3, 6] z[3] z[6] + 100 a[4, 6] z[4] z[6] + 
   121 a[5, 6] z[5] z[6] + 72 a[6, 6] z[6]^2 + 
   100 a[3, 7] z[3] z[7] + 121 a[4, 7] z[4] z[7] + 
   144 a[5, 7] z[5] z[7] + 169 a[6, 7] z[6] z[7] + 
   98 a[7, 7] z[7]^2 + 121 a[3, 8] z[3] z[8] + 
   144 a[4, 8] z[4] z[8] + 169 a[5, 8] z[5] z[8] + 
   196 a[6, 8] z[6] z[8] + 225 a[7, 8] z[7] z[8] + 
   128 a[8, 8] z[8]^2 + 144 a[3, 9] z[3] z[9] + 
   169 a[4, 9] z[4] z[9] + 196 a[5, 9] z[5] z[9] + 
   225 a[6, 9] z[6] z[9] + 256 a[7, 9] z[7] z[9] + 
   289 a[8, 9] z[8] z[9] + 162 a[9, 9] z[9]^2 + 
   169 a[3, 10] z[3] z[10] + 196 a[4, 10] z[4] z[10] + 
   225 a[5, 10] z[5] z[10] + 256 a[6, 10] z[6] z[10] + 
   289 a[7, 10] z[7] z[10] + 324 a[8, 10] z[8] z[10] + 
   361 a[9, 10] z[9] z[10] + 200 a[10, 10] z[10]^2 + 
   196 a[3, 11] z[3] z[11] + 225 a[4, 11] z[4] z[11] + 
   256 a[5, 11] z[5] z[11] + 289 a[6, 11] z[6] z[11] + 
   324 a[7, 11] z[7] z[11] + 361 a[8, 11] z[8] z[11] + 
   400 a[9, 11] z[9] z[11] + 441 a[10, 11] z[10] z[11] + 
   242 a[11, 11] z[
     11]^2 + (225 a[3, 12] z[3] + 256 a[4, 12] z[4] + 
      289 a[5, 12] z[5] + 324 a[6, 12] z[6] + 361 a[7, 12] z[7] + 
      400 a[8, 12] z[8] + 441 a[9, 12] z[9] + 
      484 a[10, 12] z[10] + 529 a[11, 12] z[11]) z[12] + 
   288 a[12, 12] z[12]^2 + 
   z[2] (1 + 25 a[2, 3] z[3] + 36 a[2, 4] z[4] + 
      49 a[2, 5] z[5] + 64 a[2, 6] z[6] + 81 a[2, 7] z[7] + 
      100 a[2, 8] z[8] + 121 a[2, 9] z[9] + 144 a[2, 10] z[10] + 
      169 a[2, 11] z[11] + 196 a[2, 12] z[12]))) + 
   2 (z[2] (-2 + 75 a[2, 3] z[3] + 108 Sqrt[2] a[2, 4] z[4] + 
   147 Sqrt[3] a[2, 5] z[5] + 384 a[2, 6] z[6] + 
   243 Sqrt[5] a[2, 7] z[7] + 300 Sqrt[6] a[2, 8] z[8] + 
   363 Sqrt[7] a[2, 9] z[9] + 864 Sqrt[2] a[2, 10] z[10] + 
   1521 a[2, 11] z[11] + 588 Sqrt[10] a[2, 12] z[12]) + 
   3 (49 a[3, 4] z[3] z[4] + 64 Sqrt[2] a[3, 5] z[3] z[5] + 
   100 Sqrt[2] a[4, 6] z[4] z[6] + 
   121 Sqrt[3] a[4, 7] z[4] z[7] + 169 a[6, 7] z[6] z[7] + 
   288 a[4, 8] z[4] z[8] + 196 Sqrt[2] a[6, 8] z[6] z[8] + 
   225 a[7, 8] z[7] z[8] + 169 Sqrt[5] a[4, 9] z[4] z[9] + 
   225 Sqrt[3] a[6, 9] z[6] z[9] + 
   256 Sqrt[2] a[7, 9] z[7] z[9] + 289 a[8, 9] z[8] z[9] + 
   196 Sqrt[6] a[4, 10] z[4] z[10] + 512 a[6, 10] z[6] z[10] + 
   289 Sqrt[3] a[7, 10] z[7] z[10] + 
   324 Sqrt[2] a[8, 10] z[8] z[10] + 361 a[9, 10] z[9] z[10] + 
   225 Sqrt[7] a[4, 11] z[4] z[11] + 
   289 Sqrt[5] a[6, 11] z[6] z[11] + 648 a[7, 11] z[7] z[11] + 
   361 Sqrt[3] a[8, 11] z[8] z[11] + 
   400 Sqrt[2] a[9, 11] z[9] z[11] + 441 a[10, 11] z[10] z[11] + 
   512 Sqrt[2] a[4, 12] z[4] z[12] + 
   324 Sqrt[6] a[6, 12] z[6] z[12] + 
   361 Sqrt[5] a[7, 12] z[7] z[12] + 800 a[8, 12] z[8] z[12] + 
   441 Sqrt[3] a[9, 12] z[9] z[12] + 
   484 Sqrt[2] a[10, 12] z[10] z[12] + 529 a[11, 12] z[11] z[12] +
    z[3] (81 Sqrt[3] a[3, 6] z[6] + 200 a[3, 7] z[7] + 
      121 Sqrt[5] a[3, 8] z[8] + 144 Sqrt[6] a[3, 9] z[9] + 
      169 Sqrt[7] a[3, 10] z[10] + 392 Sqrt[2] a[3, 11] z[11] + 
      675 a[3, 12] z[12]) + 
   z[5] (81 a[4, 5] z[4] + 121 a[5, 6] z[6] + 
      144 Sqrt[2] a[5, 7] z[7] + 169 Sqrt[3] a[5, 8] z[8] + 
      392 a[5, 9] z[9] + 225 Sqrt[5] a[5, 10] z[10] + 
      256 Sqrt[6] a[5, 11] z[11] + 289 Sqrt[7] a[5, 12] z[12])));

  vector z={z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5], z[6], z[7], z[8], z[9], z[10], z[11], z[12]};
```

The answer is very clear. I just want to know how to get the matrix a, the length-12 vector b, and scalar c in an efficient way.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code you use to get the actual values for your {a,b,c}?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that may help is to make it a univariate function in a new variable `t` and extract derivatives. Below I changed your code to remove a space between `vector` and `z` on the last line or so.

```
With[{fexpt = fexp /. Thread[vectorz -> t*vectorz]},
 c = fexpt /. t -> 0;
 bvec = With[{der = D[fexpt, t] /. t -> 0}, Map[D[der, #] &, vectorz]];
 amat = With[{der = D[fexpt, {t, 2}]/2 /. t -> 0}, 
   1/2*Outer[D[der, ##] &, vectorz, vectorz]];
 {amat, bvec, c}]
```

I do not know if this is fastest possible, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: This is indeed very fast, but it does not return correct values.

Comment: @whuber Might be the factors of 2 in the `a` matrix.

Comment: @whuber Actually it's a dearth of sharps, which by habit I have used only frugally since childhood. Should have been Outer[D[der, ##] &, vectorz, vectorz]]. Will edit.

Comment: I'm glad it's such a simple fix, because my initial tests showed your solution to be twice as fast as mine :-).

Comment: @whuber Yours is coming in twice as fast as mine over here. I think we should swap computers.

Comment: Strange.  You're getting correct answers *and* your timing on this machine is 0.00388 seconds compared to 0.00943 on mine (based on 100 iterations of each).  I'm still using *MMA* 8.0 on a four-core Xeon (about three years old).

Comment: @whuber I ran also using 100 iterations, on a Linux platform (that might or might not be relevant). In version 9 your's seems to be almost 3x faster. In version 8.0.4 yours remains unchanged but now they are nearly a dead heat. Maybe something got slower so I'll take a look.

Comment: Okay, the slowdown is real. Reported as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your fix. This is a very nice method!

Answer (score 5):

`CoefficientRules` seems to do a good job. Its results have to be transformed into actual arrays afterwards, but the timing is fast.

I am confident that those with greater facility in pattern manipulation can simplify this code, but it does work, albeit inelegantly.  Most of the effort lies in constructing the matrix.  The two forms of `ij` transmute expressions of the form `{0,0,..,0,1,0,..,0,1,0,..0}->k` to `{{i,j}->k/2,{j,i}->k/2}` and `{0,...,0,2,0,...,0}->k` to `{i,i}->k`, respectively, where `i` and `j` are the positions of the nonzero coefficients.  Note the need in the first case to symmetrize the matrix by halving its off-diagonal values and replicating them across the diagonal.  The output is cast into the form expected by `SparseArray`.

```
vector = Array[z, 12];
ij[Rule[x_, k_]] := With[{i = Flatten[Position[x, 1, 1, 2]]}, {i -> k/2, Reverse[i] -> k/2}];
ij[Rule[x : {___, 2, ___}, k_]] := With[{i = Position[x, 2, 1, 1]}, Flatten[{i, i}] -> k];
{a2, b1, c0} = Block[{r, a2, b1, c0},
    r = CoefficientRules[fexp, vector];
    c0 = First[Select[r, Plus @@ (#[[1]]) == 0 &] /. Rule[_, c_] :> c];
    b1 = Plus @@ (Select[r, Plus @@ (#[[1]]) == 1 &] /. 
        Rule[i_, x_] :> x i);
    a2 = Select[r, Plus @@ (#[[1]]) == 2 &];
    a2 = SparseArray[Flatten[a2 /. x_Rule :> ij[x]]];
    {a2, b1, c0}
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> $\{0.0090005, Null\}$

**To check**, let's compare the value calculated with `{a2, b1, c0}` to `fexp`:

```
vector . a2 . vector + b1.vector + c0 - fexp // Simplify
```

> $0$

It truly is the same.

This method *assumes* the input really is a quadratic form in the `z[..]` (including linear forms and constants as special cases).  If not, the output will be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! I learn a lot from your code.